# Force "panend" during current pan using Hammer.js 2.0.4

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I'm using Hammer.js to listen for horizontal pan on an element.
When the deltaX has reached a threshold I would like to kill the current pan forcing a "panend" and resuming panning the next time a user attempts a "panstart".

Reading through the documentation it doesn't appear to be possible with the library right now.
Anyone know of a solution?

```
    var mc = new Hammer.Manager(@option_elm.get(0),
        recognizers: [
            [Hammer.Pan,{direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL}]
        ]
    )

    mc.on('panleft', function(e) {
        e.kill() // something simple like this...?
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Hammer.js has a build in method named `stop();`. You can use it like this inside your "penleft" event function: `mc.stop();`

http://hammerjs.github.io/api/#stop%28[force]%29

This wont force "penend". Hammer.js will just ignore all inputs. Unfortunately this method has a huge bug. The event object will have wrong parameters on all new inputs:
https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/811

So i used to use a helper variable, called "isFired". Your code can look something like this:

```
var mc = new Hammer.Manager(@option_elm.get(0),
        recognizers: [
            [Hammer.Pan,{direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL}]
        ]
    ),
    isFired = false;

mc.on('panstart', function(e) {
     isFired = false;
});
mc.on('panleft', function(e) {
    if (!isFired) {
        isFired = true;
        yourCustomCallback();
    }
});
mc.on('panend', function(e) {
     isFired = false;
});
```

It is important to reset this variable to `false` on "penstart" and "panend".